# What is the name of this function space?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lp-spaces

Say $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ are measure spaces and $X : S \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a measurable function. The Wikipedia article on the Minkowski inequality ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski's_integral_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski%27s_integral_inequality)) defines the quantity
$$
   || X ||_{p,q} = \big( \int_S \big(\int_\Omega |X|^q dP\big)^{\frac p q} d\mu \big)^{\frac 1 p}   
$$
and the function space $\mathcal L_{p,q}$, in which it is finite. The article states that these function spaces have been studied, but gives no source. I also wasn't able to find any other resources.

I'm interested because I'm investigating the setting where $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is a probability triple and $X$ a stochastic process, in which the pointwise expectation
$$
\mathbb E[X] : S \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb R}, s \mapsto \mathbb E[X(s)]
$$
satisfies $\mathbb E[|X|^q]^{1/q} \in \mathcal L_p$, i.e.
$$
    || X ||_{p,q} =\big( \int_S \big( \int_\Omega |X|^q dP \big)^{\frac p q} d\mu \big)^{\frac 1 p} = ||\mathbb E[|X|^q]^{\frac 1 q} ||_p < \infty
$$
and hence $X \in \mathcal L_{p,q}$.

Comment: In the specific case of the Lebesgue measures I've seen these spaces be referred to as "mixed Lebesgue spaces", if that's any help.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!